# Fix element in parent element

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

I would like to have an element (h1) act like `position:fixed` inside of another element (a section). The h1 should stay fixed on a certain spot on the viewport, but has to disappear when scrolled past the section (because it's still inside the section). This works just fine with a background image, but unfortunately `position:fixed` fixes the h1 element inside the viewport and ignores the surrounding section element.

Is there any way this is possible to do this with preferably only HTML & CSS?

(The way the background is fixed:

```
section {
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
   background-size: cover;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-position: center center;
}

section:first-child {
   background-image: url(img/1.jpg);
}

section:nth-child(2) {
   background-image: url(img/2.jpg);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like `position:sticky` but it doesn't have full browser support just yet. However, all you have stated is a requirement. What have you attempted so far?

Comment: Can't you use `position: absolute` ? [link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

Comment: I've tried different combinations of absolute/relative positioning and even tried changing the content of the h1 element in javascript, but I felt like this should be doable in just HTML/CSS as background-fixed works just as I expected.

Comment: On the left side of your question, the upvote/downvote tool has this feature. After examining the page code, I could see it's a table cell that takes the whole paragraph height, inside which the div is scrolling. But you'll need some JS to detect the position of the div inside the cell, and decide when to lock or unlock it.

Comment: Position absolute fixes the element on a certain spot inside the section, but scrolls with the section as well.

Comment: `position:sticky` almost does the trick, but it still scrolls along with the section until it hits a certain spot (rijkvanzanten/school/portfolio)

Comment: Maybe  [this](http://jsfiddle.net/babinho/9bRg9/2/) or [this](http://jsfiddle.net/oskarrough/SFyCj/) can help you.

Comment: Jeremy, both those links mimick the position:sticky in JavaScript. It's the best alternative but still not quite what I'm looking for. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do, is wrapping the content of your container inside a `div` with the rule `position:absolute` and `position:relative` for the outer container. Then use `overflow:auto` on the *inner* wrapper, so that when you scroll, you won't be scrolling the outer container but the inner. That way when you use `position:absolute` on another element inside your outer container, it will appear to be `fixed` inside the outer container. It won't move when you scroll the content of the container, but will move with the container, which I assume is what you were looking for. To put your "fixed" element on top of the content, use `z-index:1`

```
<div class="container"> <!-- use position:relative -->
    <div class="fixed-inside-container">"Fixed"</div> <!-- use position:absolute; z-index:1; -->
    <div class="container-content"></div> <!-- use position:absolute; height:100%; overflow:auto; -->
</div>
```

Here's a fiddle demo for you: https://jsfiddle.net/ilpo/ht2j81Lt/

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this jquery:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(window).height() ) {        
        $(".first-text").addClass("absolute");
        $(".second-text").addClass("fixed");        
     }   
    else {
        $(".first-text").removeClass("absolute");
        $(".second-text").removeClass("fixed");    
    }
});
```

so you change the `position`of your text (from absolute to fixed) adding a class when you change your sliders as in this example:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/p4oo9q0h/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this pluin: https://github.com/gwdhost/SnapToTop, it can position the element where you like it.